# Use induction to show that maximum of $k$ real-valued continuous functions is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

For this question I must use induction to show that if $f_i$, $i=1, \cdots, k$ are continuous real-valued functions on $S$, then

$$h(x)=\max_{i=1, \cdots, k} f_i(x)$$ 
is continuous. So I am not even sure what to use for my base case and how to start out this problem.

Comment: What variable are you doing induction on? What's the smallest value for that variable that you need to prove the result for? That's your base case.

Comment: Well the first part of this is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032080/show-that-mx-y-maxx-y-is-continuous-on-r2/1032087#1032087

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\max_{1\le k\le n+1}f_k(x)=\max\bigl\{\max_{1\le k\le n}f_k(x),f_{n+1}(x)\bigr\}
$$

Thus the proof reduces to show that, if $f$ and $g$ are continuous, then $\max\{f,g\}$ is continuous.

The base case is, of course, $n=1$ (which is trivial).

Answer (score 0):

The base case is simply that $f_1(x)$ is continuous.

For the induction step assume that $h_{k-1}(x) = \max_{i \in \{1, 2, \cdots, k-1\}} f_i(x)$ is continuous. Now we need to prove that $h_{k}(x) = \max_{i \in \{1, 2, \cdots, k\}} f_i(x)$ is continuous.  Since $h_{k}(x) = \max \{ h_{k-1}(x), f_k(x) \}$. So we only need to prove that the maximum of two continuous functions is continuous.

Consider an arbitrary $x \in S$, since both $f_k$  and $h_{k-1}$ are continuous at $x$. For $\epsilon/2 > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $y \in B_\delta(x) \implies f_k(y) \in B_{\epsilon/2}(f_k(x))$  and $\omega > 0$ such that $y \in B_\omega(x) \implies h_{k-1}(y) \in B_{\epsilon/2}(h_{k-1}(x))$.

Let $d = \min\{\delta, \omega\}$. From the earlier argument, we can show that for all $y \in B_d(x) \implies h_k(y) \in B_{\epsilon} (h_k(x))$.

I hope that helps. Here $B_d(x)$ denotes the open ball around $x$ of radius $d$.